# Jsonb extract in PostgresSQL - problem with '{}'::

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have this jsonb column in a PostgresSQL table.

```
{
"{\"start\":\"14:00\",\"end\":\"14:50\"}",
"{\"start\":\"14:51\",\"end\":\"15:40\"}",
"{\"start\":\"15:41\",\"end\":\"16:30\"}",
"{\"start\":\"16:31\",\"end\":\"17:20\"}"
}
```

I need to extract all values of start and end.
I want the result to be like this

```
id | start1 | end1 | start2 | end2 | start3 | end3 | start4 | end4
```

or

```
id | start1 | end1 
id | start2 | end2 
id | start3 | end3 
id | start4 | end4
```

The usual ->> doesn't work for this and I have no clue how can I do that.

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Shouldn't the surrounding curly brackets (`{}`) be square brackets instead (`[]`)? Or maybe you are showing several rows of data here? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi Fabiola welcome to the SO community. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances you chance of getting a successful answer.  In this case post your table description and sample data as text - **no images** and the expected results of  that data. Also post what you tried, what it gives and how it differs from your expectations.

Comment: The escaped double quotes look very wrong. That's not how JSON is stored. Also: multiple items need to be inside of an array, your nesting of objects is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of Postgres you are using, but if it probably has:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-compatible.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-COMPATIBLE-VERSION

standard_conforming_strings (boolean)

```
This controls whether ordinary string literals ('...') treat backslashes The presence of this parameter can also be taken as an indication that the escape string syntax (E'...') is supported. Escape string syntax (Section 4.1.2.2) should be used if an application desires backslashes to be treated as escape characters.
```

In that case to deal with the escapes in your JSON you need to do:

```
select E'{\"start\":\"14:00\",\"end\":\"14:50\"}'::jsonb;
               jsonb                
------------------------------------
 {"end": "14:50", "start": "14:00"}
(1 row)

select E'{\"start\":\"14:00\",\"end\":\"14:50\"}'::jsonb ->> 'start';
 ?column? 
----------
 14:00


select E'[
{\"start\":\"14:00\",\"end\":\"14:50\"},
{\"start\":\"14:51\",\"end\":\"15:40\"},
{\"start\":\"15:41\",\"end\":\"16:30\"},
{\"start\":\"16:31\",\"end\":\"17:20\"}
]'::jsonb;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"end": "14:50", "start": "14:00"}, {"end": "15:40", "start": "14:51"}, {"end": "16:30", "start": "15:41"}, {"end": "17:20", "start": "16:31"}]
```